# Directus - create a file in a hook

Tags: directus

I am using hooks to update some data when the user uploads a file.

One of the use-cases is that we want to generate a "preview-image" from the input data, upload it and attach it to the item.

https://docs.directus.io/extensions/hooks.html#creating-hooks

How can I access the API or create/save a directus file entry within the hooks?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the API normally within a hook. So you can use the "Create File" endpoint to upload the preview image, within a blocking `files.create.before` (in v9).

https://github.com/directus/next/blob/main/docs/guides/extensions/api-hooks.md

That said, Directus will automatically create preview images using the thumbnailing system... so you shouldn't even have to build this custom.

https://docs.directus.io/guides/files.html#asset-middleware

Comment: Can you point to an example how to access the api within a hook? I've assume there is something like: $container->get('api') or something similar, but I couldn't find one. 

```
$app = \Directus\Application\Application::getInstance();
    $container = $app->getContainer();
```

Comment: The previews I want to generate are for PDF Files, afaik that is not covered for the moment

Comment: Ah, yes, PDF thumbnails are not included as of yet, but I believe there is a feature request for them. As for the hooks, you can ask around the community, but the docs for accessing data internally haven't been written for v9 yet:

https://github.com/directus/next/blob/main/docs/guides/extensions/accessing-data.md

Comment: both links are dead